# How can i access a static class member?

Tags: c++, class

```
class Point
{
  private:
    int X, Y;  
  public:
    static const Point Origin;
    static const Point OneZero;
    static const Point ZeroOne;
};
```

How can i acces the point Origin?

Comment: Add getters to access private members. `int getX()` and `int getY()`

Comment: ADD class methods like: `getX() {return this->x}`

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? I also wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: @andre Same fun name!

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan this ??? if member is static, how can you use this, which is the pointer to instance of class???

Comment: @spin Yes if member is static don't use this

Comment: @MikeSeymour - deleted, but I'm puzzled about embedded objects of the same type - unclean IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a static, write:

```
Point::Origin
```

or a more complete example:

```
namespace Someplace {
int fun() {
  return Point::Origin.X;
}
}
```

although the qualification `Point::` is not necessary when inside the class' scope -- you can simply write `Origin`.

Answer (score 1):

Add accessors ("getters") to your class as follows:

```
class Point
{
  private:
    int X, Y;  
  public:
    static const Point Origin;
    static const Point OneZero;
    static const Point ZeroOne;

    int getX() {return X;}
    int getY() {return Y;}
};
```

Then you can access the contents of a Point like this:

```
int originX = Origin.getX();
```

Or like this:

```
Point myPoint;
int pointX = myPoint.getX();
```

Also, it's confusing that there are static instances of the class Point within the class Point. The following might be more what you're trying to do:

```
class Point
{
  public:
    // Added a constructor that takes two arguments
    Point(int pointX, int pointY) {X = pointX; Y = pointY;}

    int getX() {return X;}
    int getY() {return Y;}
  private:
    int X, Y;  
};

int main()
{
  const Point Origin(0,0);
  const Point OneZero(1,0);
  const Point ZeroOne(0,1);

  int originX = Origin.getX();
};
```